# Are Gods punished for their mortal sins?

Tags: gods, avatars

If a God in his/her incarnation commits a sin is he/she ever punished? Or are they exempted from punishment because they are Gods?

Examples will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the below text you will see that Indra/Vishnu who are God were also afflicted by sin, so do you think an Avataar if he/she commits a sin would be spared?

[SB 6.13](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/13): King Indra Afflicted by Sinful Reaction

> This chapter describes Indra’s fear at having killed a brāhmaṇa
>   (Vṛtrāsura), and it also describes how he fled and was saved by the
>   grace of Lord Viṣṇu.
>
> When all the demigods requested Indra to kill Vṛtrāsura, he refused
>   because Vṛtrāsura was a brāhmaṇa. The demigods, however, encouraged
>   Indra not to fear killing him because Indra was protected by the
>   Nārāyaṇa-kavaca, or the Supreme Personality of Godhead Himself, Lord
>   Nārāyaṇa. Even by a glimpse of the chanting of Nārāyaṇa’s name, one
>   becomes free from all the sinful reactions of killing a woman, a cow
>   or a brāhmaṇa. The demigods advised Indra to perform an aśvamedha
>   sacrifice, by which Nārāyaṇa would be pleased, for the performer of
>   such a sacrifice is not implicated in sinful reactions even if he
>   kills the entire universe.

Also [refer](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gpu/gpu07.htm) text from Garuda Puran that supports the above story:

> The murderer of a Brāhmaṇ becomes consumptive, the killer of a cow
>   becomes hump-backed and imbecile, the murderer of a virgin becomes
>   leprous,--all three born as outcastes.

Other stories:

Curse of Jalandhar's wife

> In another time, there is a great Rakshasa named Jalandhara. Shiva
>   fights a fierce battle against him, but is unable to kill the demon.
>   Vishnu learns that Jalandhara's immunity it due to the piousness of
>   his wife, Vrinda. So, Vishnu takes the form of Jalandhara in front of
>   Vrinda, and she embraces him thinking he is her husband. When Vrinda
>   realizes she was tricked, she curses Vishnu that some day his own wife
>   will be stolen from him, and then commits suicide. With Vrinda now
>   deceased, Shiva is able to defeat Jalandhara.

Comment: How was Vishnu cursed?

Comment: @shreyas Vishnu showed Vrinda fearful nightmares of Jalandhar's death. Vrinda woke up and restless went out with her attendants in a garden. There Vishnu showed her two demons, then Vrinda ran with fear and there was a Muni , she took refuge to him and Muni frightened the two demons. This Muni too was a magic of Vishnu. Then Vrinda bowed to muni and asked him to tell about her husband Jalandhar. The Muni called some monkeys and they brought Jalandhar's cut head and body. Vrinda mourned a lot and asked the Muni to revive life in Jalandhar. The Muni revived life in him and went away.

Comment: This Jalandhar was actually Vishnu. Then Vishnu in disguise and Vrinda held sexual courtings. One day after intercourse Vrinda got to know that it is Vishnu. Then She cursed him this- 1. The way you Showed me two demons, the same demons will take away your wife. 2. The way you Showed me monkeys bringing Jalandhar's dead body, you will also have to take help of monkeys to get your wife. 3. Though you are knower of everything, still you did not see my love to Jalandhar, as if you are knower of nothing, same way for 1 janma you will not know who you are. @shreyas